# UIWebview white screen after application enters foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

my application is just a simple webview which loads a given url. My problem is that if I turn on my application after some time, the webview doesn't show its content any more. My question is how to know if a webview has rendered something, or is it showing white screen and i have to reload it.

I've searched SO with no luck, so I would appreciate any suggestions or directions to sites where I could find a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

In case anyone needs this I'm loading content like this and everything works, except when i don't use it for some time and it sits in the background, after it enters foreground it is white. I guess iOS is handling memory this way, and clears the webview.

```
- (void)loadWebView
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    long unixTimeStamp = (long)[date timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurlExample.com/mobile/?timestamp=%lu&secret=%@",unixTimeStamp,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kUniqueUserSecretID]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];

    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies: cookies];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way might be to use `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to check on the web view's content. For example, you could do something like:

```
NSString *head = 
    [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
        @"document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")"];
```

Comment: yes maybe this would work, i'll try, thank you! Maybe you know why the content is removed in UIWebView after some time? Maybe i can prevent this behaviour somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the problem occurs when you foreground the app?
You can do something like this in your AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

   // Depending on the architecture of your app, grab the handler to your controller that contains the webView
  [webViewController.webview reload];
}
```

Comment: yes but i want to know before i reload, if something is displayed maybe the user left this screen on purpose, and wants to do something with it later.